# Can I combine php-functions with self-declared functions?

Tags: php

I wanted to know if I could combine Php-functions with my own, self-declared functions. for example, if I make a function like this,

```
function Example_function()
{
   $Result

   return $Result;
}
```

And lets say that `$Result` is filled with some database data, can I call a php-function onto my own function like,

```
if (Example_function()->num_rows > 0)
{
   //some code
}
```

Comment: Yes, through inheritance.

Comment: Worth noting that `num_rows` doesn't sound like a very useful function to have at all.

Comment: If `$Result` has a `num_rows` property then yes. Your question lacks quite a bit of information though (preferably with a more concrete example).